# Python 2.7, OS portable way to determine permissions / contents of a puser entered path

Tags: python, file-io, io, file-permissions, file-handling

Disclaimer:  i have searched genericly (Google) and here for some information on this topic, but most of the answers are either very old, or don't seem to quite make sense to me, so I appologize in advance if this seems simple or uninformed.

Problem:  My app accepts command line input which may be either a path or a file and I need to determine several things about it.

1. Is it a path or file,
2. Is it relative or absolute
3. Is it readable and / or writable (need read and write test results)(ignoring the possibility of a race situation)

One caveat, while a

```
    try:
        file=open(filename,'w')
    except OSError as e:
        {miscellaneous error handling code here}
```

would obviously tell me if the parameter (filename in above example) existed/ was writable etc.  I do not understand enough about exception codes to know how to interpret the result of exception.  It also wouldn't provide the relative/absolute information.

Assuming that there is no one method to do this then I would need to know three things:

1. How to determine relative / absolute
2. Is it pointing to a file or a directory
3. can the EUID of the program read the location, and same for write.

I am seeking to learn from the information I gather here, and I am new to python and have bit off a significant project.  I have mastered all of it except this part.  Any help would be appreciated.  (Pointers to good help sites welcome!)(except docs.python.org that ones bookmarked already ;-)  )

Comment: my thanks to ChrisC Himanshu and Kindall.  Between the answers and comments provided I now know how to do it,  Unfortunately I have to do it in the manner i was trying to avoid, but such is life.  My thanks to you all for fast and good answers.

Comment: Posted as solved (Credit to Himanshu since he and ChrisC answered within moments of each other i based it on who had the lowest count...sorry chris but I like to help the little guy)  My thanks to all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers. The [documentations](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) specifies that the following works for both windows and linux.

1. How to determine relative / absolute
   [os.path.isabs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs) returns True if the path is absolute, False if not.
2. Is it pointing to a file or a directory
   Similarly Use [os.path.isdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) to find out if the path is directory or not.
   YOu can use [os.path.isfile(path)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to find out if the path is file or not.
3. can the EUID of the program read the location, and same for write.
   You can use [os.access(path, mode)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.access) to know if operations requiring permissions specified by mode are possible on file specified by path or not.
   P.S. This will not work for files being accessed over the network. You can use [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) This is the right way to get all the information. However it is a more costly call and hence, you should try and get all the info in one call . To interpret the results, you can use the [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) module

Comment: OK, point 1 and two solved.
I saw the information about os.access, but this disturbed me:
        

(Note

I/O operations may fail even when access() indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model.)   (copied from the page http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir)

Comment: yes, `os.access()` isn't going to respect ACLs. This is the usual way of doing permissions in Windows and is also supported by some UNIXes (I know Mac OS X does). The only cross-platform way to know whether a file is writable is to open it for writing.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I think os.stat is the right way to get the information. http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat. However it is a more costly call and hence, you should try and get all the info in one call

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) would take care of most of these needs with isabs(), isfile(), isdir(), etc.  Off the top of my head I can't think of a function that will give a simple True/False for read/write access for a given file, but one way to tackle this might be to use the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories) module's stat function and have a look at the file's permissions and owner.

Comment: The documentation for os.stat baffled me.  It would appear to be the obvious choice though.  I questioned that because it said it looks at the files permissions for both group and owner, and as far as I know (limited knowledgte here) windows does not use those data in their system, although I suppose it must be there somewhere.